# How to Catch Error: connect ECONNREFUSED at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, observable, nestjs

I am using `@nestjs/axios` in my NestJS backend application to call an endpoint as bellow:

```
this.httpService.get('some url').pipe(
  catchError(e => {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException('error');
  }),
  map(res => {
    console.log('succeeded');
  })
);
```

The problem is that when the endpoint is available then the `succeeded` will be reached, but when the endpoint is not available the `catchError` is never reached and `succeeded` neither.